# PlayFramework: WS get JSON and persist it in Action

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm working on persistence `Action`. Inside of it I need to call WS, to determine location by post code:

http://uk-postcodes.com/api

Post code I receive from the request, for its processing I use:

```
def futureLocationForPostCode(postcode: String): Option[Location] = {
    val postcodeWithoutSpace = postcode.replaceAll(" ", "");
    val url = "http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/"+postcodeWithoutSpace+".json"
    val holder: WSRequestHolder = WS.url(url)

    val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = holder.get()

    val result = futureResponse match {
      case response: WSResponse => response.status match {
        case 200 => {
          val lat = (response.json \ "geo" \ "lat").as[Double]
          val lon = (response.json \ "geo" \ "lng").as[Double]
          val location: Location = Location(lat, lon)
          location
        }
        case _ => None
      }
    }
    result
  }
```

And here is a model of `Location`:

```
case class Location(lat: Double, lon: Double)

object Location {

  implicit val locationReads: Format[Location] = (
    (JsPath \ "lat").format[Double](min(-90.0) keepAnd max(90.0)) and
    (JsPath \ "lon").format[Double](min(-180.0) keepAnd max(180.0))
  )(Location.apply, unlift(Location.unapply))

}
```

I don't know how to save the Location if it is not None in the `Action`:

```
def createAccount = Action.async {
    implicit request => {
      createAccountForm.bindFromRequest fold (
        formWithErrors => {
          Logger.info("Validation errors")
          Future.successful(BadRequest(createAccountForm.errorsAsJson))
        },
        accountInfo => {
          AccountService.findByEmail(accountInfo.email) map {
            case accountOpt: Option[Account] => accountOpt match {
              case Some(acc) => BadRequest(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> "Email is already in use")))
              case None => {
                Logger.info("Created account")
                val account = Account.createAccount(accountInfo)

                //TODO: Add location to account if it is not None
                val futureLocation = Account.futureLocationForPostCode(accountInfo.postCode)

                Created(Json.toJson(AccountService.add(account)))
              }
            }
            case _ => {
              Logger.info("DB connection error")
              InternalServerError(Json.toJson(Json.obj("message" -> "DB connection error")))
            }
          }
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no location? Should the account still be created without it?

Comment: @LimbSoup yes, it will be created anyway, because `Account` has location field marked as `Option[Location]`, so depends on WS response I put `None` or `Location` in the new `Account` instance

Comment: I don't think `futureLocationForPostCode` has the return type you think it does. You should really add the type annotation for it, because it looks like right now it's returning `Future[Object]` instead of `Option[Location]`

Comment: @LimbSoup absolutely right. Now I'm working on `futureLocationForPostCode`, because it does not return that type which it has to. Thanks

Comment: Right now `futureLocationForPostCode` is always going to return `None`, the future is being completely thrown away.

Comment: @Ryan now I've implemented new version of `futureLocationForPostCode`, I put it in edited version of the question, but to still doesn't work correctly =(

Comment: @AlexFruzenshtein That's always going to return `None` because your match is always going to fail and fall to the `case _ =>` case.  You have a `Future[WSResponse]` which will never match against `WSResponse`.  Change your return type to `Future[Option[Location]]` and then use map/filter/etc the future rather than match.

Comment: @Ryan ok, thanks. I'll tray this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed the wrong return type for the futureLocationForPostCode method. The following should work:

```
def futureLocationForPostCode(postcode: String): Future[Option[Location]] = {
    val postcodeWithoutSpace = postcode.replaceAll(" ", "");
    val url = "http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/"+postcodeWithoutSpace+".json"
    val holder: WSRequestHolder = WS.url(url)

    val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = holder.get()

    val result = futureResponse map { response =>
        response.status match {
            case 200 => {
                val lat = (response.json \ "geo" \ "lat").as[Double]
                val lon = (response.json \ "geo" \ "lng").as[Double]
                val location: Location = Location(lat, lon)
                Some(location)
             }
             case _ => None
        }   
    }
    result
}
```

and then

```
 val futureLocation = Account.futureLocationForPostCode(accountInfo.postCode)

 // Action.async requires a result of Future[SimpleResult] so map the future accordingly
 futureLocation map { locationOption =>
     val json = locationOption match {
         case Some(location) => {
             // here you can add location to account before return
             Json.toJson(AccountService.add(account))
         }
         case None => {
             Json.toJson(AccountService.add(account))
         }
     }

     Created(json)
 }
```

Comment: I would add recover to the future so errors will be handled too: `futureLocation.recover{ case _ => Created(Json.toJson(AccountService.add(account))) }`